# A Matter of Time

Tags: riddle

Today I thought of a simple riddle involving time.

> Name me a place where time is divided,
>   Where you can double or half it,
>   Or hold it completely still,
>   But never stop moving forward.
>
> Name me a place where you can do all that.

Hint:

> It's not a clock, and it's not a math sheet with clocks on it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably not correct, but here's the first thing that came to mind:

> A piece of music

...time is divided

> A piece of music is divided into measures based on the time signature

...double or half it...

> Could refer to tempo (increasing or decreasing the speed) or the length of different notes (whole notes, half notes, quarter notes, etc), or even changing time signatures

...hold it completely still...

> Could refer to rests, where nothing is played so the music "stops", or a fermata, where the note is held for an indeterminately long time outside the time signature

...but never stop moving forward.

> The piece of music is always moving forward to the conclusion, no matter what you do to tempo or time signature during the piece.

Comment: This *is* the answer I was thinking of!  Except that the second proof is much simpler than that - look up "double time" and "half time" to find out why.  ;)

Comment: But what about *da capo*? Aren't you going back then, instead of forward?

Comment: On the sheet of music, perhaps, but in terms of the actual performance of the piece, it's always moving forward to the end. :)

Comment: @BMWurm But you never stop *moving* forward - I thought about saying you can jump back, but never stop moving forward, but thought that might make it too confusing.

Answer (score 3):

A possible answer:

> A central processor unit (CPU)

where you can double or half it, or hold it completely still, but never stop moving forward

> You can overclock and under clock the frequency of clock cycles on a processor to make it double, or half its current speed. When the processor is off it is halted completely.

but never stop moving forward:

> In the use of 'forward' as progress, processors are always being researched for ways to be improved.

Comment: Not always you can make it double

Comment: @leoll2 You can try....it might just melt though ;P

Comment: You also split the meaning in your third proof - that place is entirely different from the place where your original answer is.  But I DO like the creativity.

Comment: @Zibbobz I was originally going to reference forward movement in time, but the current answer seemed more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is

> A videogame

Name me a place where time is divided,

> The time in a videogame is usually made of "ticks".

where you can double or half it

> You can speed up or slow down the speed of the game.

or hold it completely still

> Pause.

but never stop moving forward.

> In most videogames you cannot travel back in time.

Comment: Prince of Persia: Sands of Time would like to have a word with you.

Comment: As would Animal Crossing, though that's not technically supposed to be part of the game...

Comment: @BaileyM Mr. Resetti would like to have too many words with you.